# Best practice for configureing vmware dv uplink port groups?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, virtual-network

I'm creating a distributed virtual switch - each host has 2 physical NIC's each of which will map to an uplink port. 
I want to create uplink port groups so i can set up NIC teaming, I wanted to know if there were any best practices as to whether I should group physical NIC's from the same host into a dvuplink port group, or whether i should take physical NIC's from different hosts and group them.

So I would have either:
DV Uplink 1 with vmnic0 and vmnic1 (from host 1)
DV Uplink 2 with vmnic0 and vmnic1 (from host 2)

OR

DV Uplink 1 with vmnic0 (host 1) and vmnic0 (host 2)
DV Uplink 2 with vmnic1 (host 1) and vmnic1 (host 2)

Does it matter? Are there any best practices, and what considerations are there when more hosts are added?

Thanks in advance.